# Any way to render HTML in react-markdown

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tinymce, markdown

I am using tinymce to accept markdown data from user. The output data is html. I want to display that data on a page. I am using react-markdown for it.
I can see data on page but it's HTML tags. Is there any way to show HTML page not tags?

```js
export default function ThePage() {
  const markdown = {
    description: "<p>Hello from the other </p>\n<p><strong>side</strong></p>",
  }

  return (
    <>
      <ReactMarkdown children={markdown.description} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The `ReactMarkdown` component is for rendering mark *down*, not HTML mark *up* . Given HTML input it just escapes it, and that's why you see it as "source", not formatted text.

If you need to use it with HTML you need to apply a plugin, such as [rehypeRaw](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rehype-raw) :

```
import ReactMarkdown from "react-markdown";
import rehypeRaw from "rehype-raw";

//...

export default function ThePage() {
  const markdown = {
    description: "<p>Hello from the other </p>\n<p><strong>side</strong></p>"
  }

  return (
    <>
      <ReactMarkdown children={markdown.description} rehypePlugins={[rehypeRaw]} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: You legend!! Thanks for sharing this, that rehypeRaw plugin is pretty sweet :)

Comment: Also take a look at https://github.com/remarkjs/remark-gfm plugin for react-markdown to allow redendering of strikethrough, checkboxes and tables in markdown.

Comment: I tried this and it is not working it crashes forme

Comment: 2023 update; to prevent Typescript complaining use `rehypePlugins={[rehypeRaw] as any}`

Comment: Just to clarify, could this cause a cross-site scripting vulnerability when rendering un-trusted content?

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can use [react-render-markup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-render-markup) see example:

```
import { Markup } from "react-render-markup";
 export default function App(){
 return(<Markup markup={markdown.description} />)
 }
```

Comment: This is the best solution if you only have HTML, and not markdown + HTML

Comment: Then it's not an answer, the question is about combining the two!